# How to send value method GET with url mod rewrite?

Tags: php, forms, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to send value method GET with the url when using mod rewrite ?

Normally

```
<form name="f1" method="get" action="aaa.php">
    <input type="text" name="value_1" value="ddd"/>
    <input type="text" name="value_2" value="888"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

after I press submit button, I will be redirect to

`www.example.com/aaa.php?value_1=ddd&value_2=888`

but now I want to do it like this using mod rewrite

like

```
<form name="f1" method="get" action="aaa">
    <input type="text" name="value_1" value="ddd"/>
    <input type="text" name="value_2" value="888"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

after I press the submit button, I want to be redirected to

`www.example.com/aaa/ddd/888`

How can I do that ?

```
EDIT : I created a .htaccess file with success success, and it works good.
```

Comment: you have to do it through the .htaccess files

Comment: Try POST instead of GET

Comment: you should write the rules manually inside htaccess file , mod_rewrite did not auto convert your GET form submission to friendly links you should write every thing in PHP and htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourwebsite.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.yourwebsite.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9-+]*)/([a-z0-9-+]*)/([0-9]{1,3})$ /$1.php?value_1=$2&value_2=$3 [L]
```

The Regex depends on the kind of data you want to transfer (integer, string...).